# How to cut out an extra Face/extension

Tags: modifiers, faces

I created a window space using a Bool Tool modifier. [image]

Along the line, I realised there is a plane/face obstructing the entrance of the window. The plane looks like it's a face or extension from the wall of the window[image]

I'm new to blender, and unfortunately don't know a few tricks to correct that defect.

Can you please teach me how to cut out/trim out that face?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was to create vertices with edges on the wall, that had the similar shape of the window, and then extrude it inward.